# How to use `\tikzset` style as arrow style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

How can I declare a style for an arrow tip `angle=60:1mm` named `TARROW` inside `\tikzset` and then use it as an arrow style for `Stealth` arrow tip `{Stealth[TARROW]}` without error being generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly what you ask for, but you could do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
   TARROW/.tip={Stealth[angle=60:1mm]}
}
\begin{document}
\tikz \draw [-TARROW] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{document}
```

You can also use a style as an option to `Stealth`, but then you need `/tikz/TARROW`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
   TARROW/.style={angle=60:1mm}
}
\begin{document}
\tikz \draw [-{Stealth[/tikz/TARROW]}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{document}
```